# asyncio.wait_for didn't cancel the task

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

After the asyncio.wait_for timeout, the task was not cancelled

The script below is the minimized script to reproduce it. The tcp server just sent two chars after 100 seconds later after client connected

```py
import sys
import asyncio
import socket

async def test_single_call():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host='127.0.0.1', port=8888)
    try:
        msg = await asyncio.wait_for(reader.read(1), timeout=3)
        print("Unexcepted message received:" , msg, file=sys.stderr)
        assert False
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass

    msg = await reader.read(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test_single_call())
loop.close()
```

The tcpclient(code above) is expected to timeout 3 seconds later, and read again after that; but it seems the task was not cancelled after it was timeout. My python version is 3.6.9

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcpclient.py", line 17, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(test_single_call())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "tcpclient.py", line 14, in test_single_call
    msg = await reader.read(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/streams.py", line 634, in read
    yield from self._wait_for_data('read')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/streams.py", line 452, in _wait_for_data
    'already waiting for incoming data' % func_name)
RuntimeError: read() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data
```

I also uploaded the tcp server [here](https://gist.github.com/ZhuBicen/a5d6e99d76deed856fc0a4b969131cb0)

Comment: it can be reproduced on docker image: python:3.6.15-bullseye

Answer (score 0):

For Linux Python 3.6, it had this issue. two options:

1. Upgrade to Python 3.8 or 3.9
2. Replace the `open_connection` and `StreamReader` with `loop.sock_connet`, `loop.sock_recv`, `loop.sock_sendall`

eg:

```py
import sys
import asyncio
import socket

async def test_single_call(loop):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock = await loop.sock_connect(sock, server_address)

    try:
        msg = await asyncio.wait_for(loop.sock_recv(sock, 1), timeout=3)
        print("Unexcepted message received:" , msg, file=sys.stderr)
        assert False
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass

    msg = await loop.sock_recv(sock, 1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test_single_call(loop))
loop.close()
```